# Code signing for iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive an iOS touch framework project. But getting following error:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework'
>   in SDK 'iOS 9.0'

Even if I set to Don't Code Sign, the same error occurs. Is it mandatory to code sign iOS frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

In the iOS framework projects we cannot run in the device . So for that we do not need to set any code signing identity.

If you're facing this problem pls set **Don't code sign** in the targets.

After that clean your framework projects and restart your Xcode.

Now you try to compile , you will get build success.

Again  you faced the same issue mean you're doing something wrong. So clean all you certificate in Mac and re-install required certificate.

When need to run IOS projects in device that time only require code sign.